# FindRow with text values inside span attributes

Tags: html-table, watin

I am using Watin to find rows in a jQuery table. However, jQuery sets some of its text in a cell within a span class. Watin does not work in these cases.

```
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow("Liza", columnNum)
```

The above code works for:

```
<td>Liza</td>
```

but not for:

```
<td><span>Liza</span></td>
```

Any clue how I can tweak the Watin code to work with span classes?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the Text property to identify

```
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRowInOwnTableRows(t => t.Text.Trim()== rowidentifier, columnNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues, my recommendation is to create a helper class that's available to all your specs and you add helper functions there, such as removeHtml, wait for async request, this kind of thing. a good starting point would be these methods http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

So on your tests you can do something like

```
// where .NoHTML() is a extension method in your helper class
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value.NoHTML(), columnNum)
```

This might not be the exact answer, but I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I reckon you miss understood the question. the variable "value" is really the query, not the output of the table. Hence, it would not have any html in it. I have updated my question to avoid this confusion.

Comment: oh.. I see what you're saying now.. I'll try to run a sample and I'll update the post later on

Comment: I haven't had the time to try the sample I said, however the solution presented by @AshishNarmen seems good

Comment: the text property did not help - although it may be due to what I am testing. The code is run before the row has been inserted into the table and hence I obtain null value errors - I managed to remove the span tabs for the time being, but I think I will stumble upon this problem soon again